# Safari File Dialog Fails to Show

Tags: safari, mojave

Safari's Open / Choose File Dialog Window fails to show for any upload or select file option. This appears to be universal and the dialog window fails to show regardless of which web app, or site is being used.

A new clean account and Safe Boot exhibit the same behaviour.

- Safari: `Version 14.0.2 (14610.3.7.1.10)`
- macOS Mojave `10.14.6 (18G7016)`

Comment: I'm assuming some of this has already been covered in your tests, but just to double-check… Does it do this on all sites? Does it still do it if you close all windows then relaunch & try from a blank window? Are you in fullscreen? If not, do you have windows open in more than one Space? What Extensions do you have installed?

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for double checking. Yes, it is completely universal. No extensions installed, number of windows and Spaces has no effect

Comment: ok, then the only thing I could think of would be to overlay the OS from Recovery & see what happens - it shouldn't touch your existing data (though a backup is always wise).

Comment: @Tetsujin Ah. don't worry, I'm Time Machined to the hilt. I was testing the waters to see if anyone else has had the same issue and if there were a no OS-install route to go down.

Comment: All I can say is "it doesn't happen here" which I know is a totally useless reply ;) OS overlay is pretty quick, 20 mins or so. I used to have to do it on one of the machines here after every security update back in Sierra days (what a pita that was;)

Comment: @Tetsujin sadly an OS install doesn't work. A re-install and Time Machine restore is also pulling in the fault.

Comment: From a clean install I'd have tried it without the Time Machine restore first, just to see, but other than that, I'm out of ideas, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Tetsujin apologies, should have said, it was absolutely fine under a clean install

Comment: …then it's something already installed. If it is the same across a new admin account, then it's global. I'm not sure how you'd track that down, tbh, if you've eliminated any browser extensions as suspects.

Comment: Is this the near-ubiquitous problem of Gmail attachment button not popping up the  "open file" window? Cmd-O works fine to tell Safari to open a file, but the "add attachment" buttons on web pages do nothing. I have a new install of 10.14.6 and it is broken this way. I'ld like to hear how @Tetsujin's works OK! :-)

Comment: Ahh, I've heard of that but not experienced it. I've never had a gmail account.

Comment: @Tetsujin - It happens on any website that has a button to upload content. Gmail was just an example. Lots of discussions on the apple forums (not just here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed in the latest Safari update, 14.0.3.

More information here https://macintouch.com/community/index.php?threads/problems-with-safari-14-0-2.2926/

And here: https://mrmacintosh.com/security-updates-2020-001-for-catalina-2020-007-mojave-safari-14-0-2/